# mysql regular replace characters with empty char

Tags: mysql

I have the following strings in the table:

```
step1.cards.choice_step_1
step1.cards.choice_step_2

step2.cards.choice_step_1
step2.cards.choice_step_2
```

I would replace with empty characters all in these string using that pattern:

```
^step([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]).cards.choice_step_1$
^step([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]).cards.choice_step_2$
```

Does it possible to do that in MySQL?

Finally I would have in result:

```
1
1
2
2
```

**EDIT**

```
select regex_replace('[^0-9]','','step1.cards.choice_step_1');
```

return me

```
11
```

please help on correct pattern on the following data :

```
sometext.step1
sometext.step1.cards.choice_step_1
sometext.step1.cards.choice_step_2
sometext.step1.desire

sometext.step2
sometext.step2.cards.choice_step_1
sometext.step2.cards.choice_step_2
sometext.step2.desire
```

to get the following result:

```
step1
step1
step1
step1

step2
step2
step2
step2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
create table test (field1 varchar(100));
select * from test;
+------------------------------------+
| field1                             |
+------------------------------------+
| sometext.step1                     |
| sometext.step1.cards.choice_step_1 |
| sometext.step1.cards.choice_step_2 |
| sometext.step1.desire              |
| sometext.step2                     |
| sometext.step2.cards.choice_step_1 |
| sometext.step2.cards.choice_step_2 |
| sometext.step2.desire              |
| step1                              |
+------------------------------------+
```

Query:

```
select 
    field1,

    -- find position of step
    position('step' in field1) as step,

    -- find position of dot AFTER step is found
    position('.' in 
            substr(field1, position('step' in field1), length(field1))) 
            + position('step' in field1) as dot,

    -- if position of 'step' --and-- position of 'step' + position of 'dot' is 1
    --    that means: step is at position 1 and dot is not found, display field as is
    -- if position of 'step' --and-- position of 'step' + position of 'dot' are equal
    --    that means: dot is not found. Grab everything from step onwards
    -- if position of 'step' --and-- position of 'step' + position of 'dot' are **NOT** equal
    -- grab everything from where step was found thruogh just before dot was found
    case
    when position('step' in field1) = 1 
         and 
         position('.' in substr(field1, position('step' in field1), length(field1))) 
         + position('step' in field1) = 1 
         then 
            field1
    when position('step' in field1) = 
        position('.' in substr(field1, position('step' in field1), length(field1))) 
        + position('step' in field1) 
        then 
            substr(field1, position('step' in field1), length(field1))
    else 
        substr(field1, 
            position('step' in field1), 
            position('.' in substr(field1, position('step' in field1), length(field1)))-1
        )
    end as ans  

from test;
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------------+------+------+-------+
| field1                             | step | dot  | ans   |
+------------------------------------+------+------+-------+
| sometext.step1                     |   10 |   10 | step1 |
| sometext.step1.cards.choice_step_1 |   10 |   16 | step1 |
| sometext.step1.cards.choice_step_2 |   10 |   16 | step1 |
| sometext.step1.desire              |   10 |   16 | step1 |
| sometext.step2                     |   10 |   10 | step2 |
| sometext.step2.cards.choice_step_1 |   10 |   16 | step2 |
| sometext.step2.cards.choice_step_2 |   10 |   16 | step2 |
| sometext.step2.desire              |   10 |   16 | step2 |
| step1                              |    1 |    1 | step1 |
+------------------------------------+------+------+-------+
```

Notice the last field that has the data you desire. Please feel free to tweak this to your needs.